# Redirecting to a different page when link is opened in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I am really confused on how to create this, so please help me out.
I have a html page where I have added the meta fields for link preview on facebook and skype. Now what I want is when I share this link on FB or skype, it should show the link preview with the image I have specified in meta and when the user clicks on the link, this link should open in the browser and then redirected to another link which I am sending through my server using a get request?

How can I do that?

So the link should show meta information on preview and redirected to a new page when loaded in browser

```
<html>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

            function Redirect() {
               window.location="http://www.example2.com";
            }

            Redirect();

      </script>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your code here

Comment: Yes, I was able to do it. But I am unable to preview link on whatsapp, its working on facebook

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly because you're sharing a link not a webpage. Clicking a shared link will always redirect you to that link.

You could do this, have your redirect logic in your `http://example.com`
By doing this, the user will land in `http://example.com` and will be redirected automatically to `http://example2.com`

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do it, by using window.location="www.example1.com". But I am able to preview only the link on FB but not on whatsapp.